# Constant or gradual rotation from array modifier?

Tags: modeling

Is there a non-destructive way to make these leaves rotate upward gradually? I've used an array modifier with an object offset to rotate and scale them and a constant offset on the z axis to raise it up. I've tried to illustrate what I mean with the annotations.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. subdivide the cube
2. add simple deform
3. add an empty,the origin of the cube shows the point you want to rotate around, and turn the Z-axis of emtpy to the direction you want to rotate around.
4. set the simple deform as I shown.

[image]

Update:

1. right click inner angle,copy the data path
   [image]
2. right click outer angle,add driver,pay special attention to the setting I circled.
   [image]
3. then you can rotate the inner leaves and the outer leaves rotate as your formular shows.
   [image]

Comment: That almost works but they all rotate at the same angle when I need them to gradually rotate//bend more as the leaves get smaller.

Comment: I have update the answer